# Query to find numeric and text in MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, is-empty

I have written a Search query to find data from MS Access table. But when the user does not type in the number like ID, the query fails.

```
"Select UID, FirstName from tUserInfo where UID = " + UserID + " and  FirstName like '%" + txtSearchFirst.Text + "%'"
```

How to search table when the number is empty?

Comment: Atre you running this within MS Access or in c#, for example?

Comment: I am running this in C#.

Comment: In that case, you should use a parameter query or run into an sql injection problem.

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx#Y450

Comment: Agreed about sql injection problem, but it still does not solve my issue  as when ID is empty, the query fails to return anything

Comment: The solutions below dont work as when UID is blank and Username has some matching value , still it shows no rows found. I think as UID = BLANK.

Comment: I tested my example with UID = null. The param appends an empty string to UID so `UID Like ? & '%'` reads `UID Like '' & '%'`. In my test, a record was returned.

Comment: Okay, I understand, I have changed that to `And UID & "" Like ? & '%';"`

Answer (score 2):

```
Select UID, FirstName from tUserInfo 
where (UID = " + UserID + " or UID is null)
and FirstName like '%" + txtSearchFirst.Text + "%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes.

```
    thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT UID, FirstName FROM tUserInfo " +
    " WHERE FirstName Like '%' & ?  & '%' And UID & "" Like ? & '%';";

    //Names are irrelevant with OLEDB and MS Access, the order is important
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", txtSearchFirst.Text);
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", UserID + "");
```